# Resizing the table

Tags: tables

I want to create a table but there are two problems. Firstly, the size of the table is so big. The second problem is a vertical line in the first cell from the left hand. How I can Make the table smaller and also in the center of the page, also how I can remove that vertical line?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{empty}


% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Models}} & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{DR(eye)VE}  & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{DR(eye)VE} & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{DR(eye)VE} & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{DR(eye)VE}  \\ \cline{3-18}
    && CC & KLD & SIM & NSS &CC & KLD & SIM & NSS &CC & KLD & SIM & NSS &CC & KLD & SIM & NSS  \\ \cline{2-18}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this the best way to show this data to your readers? I would not want to read this kind of data rescaled or not.

Comment: Off-topic: `top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm` may be expressed more concisely as `vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set font size as `\small` and reduce the column sep. `tabularray` is easy to use.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{title}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec            = {*{17}{Q[co=-1,c,m]}},
hlines,
vlines,
cells              = {cmd=\small},
columns            = {colsep=0pt},
cell{1}{2,6,10,14} = {c=4}{},
cell{1}{1}         = {r=2}{},
}
Models & DR(eye)VE &     &     &     & DR(eye)VE &     &     &     & DR(eye)VE &     &     &     & DR(eye)VE &     &     &     \\
       & CC        & KLD & SIM & NSS & CC        & KLD & SIM & NSS & CC        & KLD & SIM & NSS & CC        & KLD & SIM & NSS \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, here's a `tabularx`-based solution, with a target width of `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[letterpaper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of `X` col. type


\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next two instructions
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\hspace{3pt}} | *{16}{C|} }
\cline{2-17}
\multirow{2}{*}{Models}
  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{DR(eye)VE} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{DR(eye)VE} 
  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{DR(eye)VE} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{DR(eye)VE} \\ 
\cline{2-17}
  & CC & KLD & SIM & NSS & CC & KLD & SIM & NSS 
  & CC & KLD & SIM & NSS & CC & KLD & SIM & NSS \\ 
\cline{2-17}
\end{tabularx}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```